# Why can't I invoke PropertyChanged event from an Extension Method?

Tags: c#, wpf, extension-methods, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

I've tried to code a class to avoid a method like "RaisePropertyChanged". I know that I can inherit from a class that has that implementation but in some cases I can't. I've tried with a Extension Method but Visual Studio complain.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void RaisePropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged predicate, string propertyName)
    {
        if (predicate.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            predicate.PropertyChanged(propertyName, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

It said:

> "The event
>   '*System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' can
>   only appear on the left hand side of += or -=*"

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I was trying to do the same thing (mixin for INotifyPropertyChanged) and ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925106/why-i-cant-invoke-propertychanged-event-from-an-extension-method/4925124#4925124) is right. However, I see what you're trying to do (make your code reusable—**good for you**); and I'll just point out that this is often easily rectified by accepting the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` *delegate* itself and passing it from within the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation:

```
public static void Raise(this PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, object sender, string propertyName)
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then from within your class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can call this extension method like so:

```
PropertyChanged.Raise(this, "MyProperty");
```

This works because, [as Marc said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925106/why-i-cant-invoke-propertychanged-event-from-an-extension-method/4925151#4925151), within the class declaring the event you *can* access it like a field (which means you can pass it as a delegate argument to a method, including extension methods).

Comment: +1. You can go even more generic and just take a `EventHandler<T>`. See the `Raise<T>` method in this class for an example: http://thehelpertrinity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/53656#2260

Comment: @Kent: I completely agree; the only annoying thing is that with a lot of BCL types you actually don't have generic `EventHandler<T>`-based events but rather these weird strongly typed delegates (e.g., `PropertyChangedEventHandler`), so you have to either accept some conversion parameter to do the trivial lambda conversion from `PropertyChangedEventHandler` to `EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>` or, more realistically, you just implement what you actually need ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can only raise an event from within the class in which it's defined.

This line:

```
predicate.PropertyChanged(propertyName, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Will fail, since `predicate` is not the class which defines this extension method.

This is partly why this is typically handled via a base class instead of via using Extension methods.

Answer (score 4):

Events are really just an API with add/remove (technically there *is* an optional "invoke" available in the CLI, but the c# compiler doesn't provide it).

What you have there is a field-like event; field-like events act as the add/remove API from *outside* the declaring type, and act like the field only **inside** the declaring type, and only when it is *necessary* to treat as a delegate - most commonly: invoking the subscribers (this is a subtle change here in c# 4; before c# 4 *all* access from *inside* the type acts against the field, including +=/-=).

An extension method *by definition* cannot be inside the declaring type - only top-level (non-nested) static classes can provide extension methods; so no extension method can *ever* have the direct ability to invoke a field-like event.

Answer (score 2):

When you define an event with the `event` keyword, the C# compiler actually generates a number of things for you behind the scenes.

```
event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

Translates to something like (though not exactly as it actually adds some locking and other checks)...

```
private EventHandler _myEvent;

public EventHandler MyEvent
{
  add( EventHandler handler )
  { 
    _myEvent += handler;
  }
  remove( EventHandler handler )
  {
    _myEvent -= handler;
  }
}
```

As you can see the actual EventHandler `_myEvent` is private and cannot be invoked directly.

Comment: Pedant point: field-like events (the above) are only generated if no `add`/`remove` implementation is provided.