# extension method to interface

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently using WPF and implementing a model related class deriving `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have found that declaring some helper methods is very useful. So I wanted to add these helper methods automatically:

```
public static class INotifyPropertyChangedHelper
{
    static void notifyPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged propertyChanged, string PropertyName = "")
    {
        // errors here
        propertyChanged.PropertyChanged(propertyChanged, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
    static bool setField<T>(this INotifyPropertyChanged propertyChanged, ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        propertyChanged.notifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Gives me a compiler error

> The event 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' can only
>       appear on the left hand side of += or -=" because PropertyChanged is an event.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/INotifyPropertyChangedExt.aspx

Comment: This answer might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4925143/2609288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy trick to do this, extension methods are static methods recognized by compiler which do not become part of class itself. As += and -= on event are accessible only form class defining the event, extension method can't help you there.

I guess you are trying to hack one of the known problems:
[Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist?lq=1)