# Where does Binding expression get executed in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a custom control which has an `ItemsSource` property:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = 
BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(RadioButtonsGroup), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            OnItemsAdded(this, new ItemsAddedEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
```

I call the `OnItemsAdded` method in the property setter, to initialize the control, 
it get called only when I set the property like this:

```
myCustomControl.ItemsSource = vm.MyList;
```

but doesn't get called when I set it through data-binding:

```
<Controls:RadioButtonsGroup ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" x:Name="myCustomControl"/>
```

so the control doesn't get the list and isn't initialized at all!

I don't want to use the `propertyChanged` delegate, because it's static and I need to use instance members in it.

Comment: PropertyChanged is the way to go. You will get the instance you need with the old and new value of that property

Comment: I subscribed to the event in the setter of the property:
`PropertyChanged += DTRadioButton_OnItemsAdded;`, but it doesn't even get called (the class inherits from `ContentView`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example how you should implement a bindable property, that is a collection

```
public class RadioButtonsGroup : View
{
    public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(ItemsSource),
        returnType: typeof(IEnumerable),
        declaringType: typeof(RadioButtonsGroup),
        defaultValue: null,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged
    );

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource 
    { 
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty,value);
    }

    // gets called from BindableProperty 
    // whenever you assign a new value to ItemsSource property
    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var @this = bindable as RadioButtonsGroup;

        // unsubscribe from the old value

        var oldNPC = oldValue as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (oldNPC != null)
        {
            oldNPC.PropertyChanged -= @this.OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged;
        }

        var oldNCC = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldNCC != null)
        {
            oldNCC.CollectionChanged -= @this.OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }

        // subscribe to the new value

        var newNPC = newValue as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (newNPC != null)
        {
            newNPC.PropertyChanged += @this.OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged;
        }

        var newNCC = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newNCC != null)
        {
            newNCC.CollectionChanged += @this.OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }

        // inform the instance to do something

        @this.RebuildOnItemsSource();
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle the collection changes
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle the property changes
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void RebuildOnItemsSource()
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null)
        {
            // clear out all
        }
        else
        {
            // complete creation of all subviews
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't PropertyChanged for collections the same as CollectionChanged?

Comment: BTW, both `OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged` and `OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged` not called?

Comment: Nope, PropertyChanged is raised, when a property has changed (f.i. Count property). CollectionChanged is raised whenever the collection has changed (f.i. item at index 0 was exchanged)

Comment: Have a look at the docs for [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) (which implements **both** notification interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the binding that the `MyList` property has changed. If you have the `MyList` property in the code-behind of the page (`xaml.cs`), it would look like this:

```
public class Detail : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private List<int> _myList;
    public List<int> MyList
    {
       get => _myList;
       set 
       {
          _myList = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged();
       } 
    }    
}
```

As you can see, you don't subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter, but rather fire it. Behind the scenes the `Binding` subscribes to this event and when it is executed it updates the value of the property on your custom control.

To react to property changes, you need to add another parameter to the `BindableProperty` definition:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = 
BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", ..., propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);

static void OnEventNameChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    // Property changed implementation goes here
}
```

There is a nice tutorial on building Custom controls with bindable properties: https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: And where is the BindableProperty?

Comment: I can't Invoke the `PropertyChanged` like you used because it's defined in the `BindableObject` class (the control inherits from `ContentView`)

Comment: You can call the `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` method on `BindableObject`

Comment: But you shouldn't invoke this in the custom control code behind, but in the code behind of the page where you actually use the control

Comment: Check out this nice tutorial on building `BindableProperties`: https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EO5HUC0.png
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925124/6197785